# Sorting output obtain by grep for timestamp

Tags: sorting, grep

My file look like this.

```
[2013] [ a] INFO : [handleMessage] Handling messages ...

[2013] [ b] INFO : [handleMessage] The message received is: [OS     OS-EVNTSVR0-H                 20130404125956465000RFST  M430   F                   ]
[2013] [ c] INFO : [handleMessage] Complete handling message.

[2013] [ a] INFO : [handleMessage] Handling messages ...

[2013] [ b] INFO : [handleMessage] The message received is: [OS     OS-EVNTSVR0-H                 20130404135956465000RFST  M430   F                   ]

[2013] [ c] INFO : [handleMessage] Complete handling message.
```

I want to capture only the message received. (Which I already did)
After capturing message I have to sort it with the time stamp value in third column. But it contain some characters in the end. ( Eg : for the above file 20130404125956465000RFST and 20130404135956465000RFST )

I got lot of messages like this and I use this command.

```
gzgrep 'The message received is:' Receiver.log.2013-04-04*.gz | cut -d"[" -f5 | sort -t -n -k3
```

But sorting with numeric won't work due to the suffix characters. Can anyone help me on this sorting part. Which need to sort in time stamp value.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sort -nk3.18` to exclude the last 4 characters in field 3.

From `man sort`:

> -k, --key=KEYDEF sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type
>
> KEYDEF  is F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]] for start and stop position, where F is a field number and C a character position in the
>   field; both are ori‐
>          gin 1, and the stop position defaults to the line's end.  If neither -t nor -b is in effect, characters in a field are counted from
>   the  beginning
>          of  the  preceding  whitespace.  OPTS is one or more single-letter ordering options [bdfgiMhnRrV], which override global
>   ordering options for that
>          key.  If no key is given, use the entire line as the key. e

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat test.log.gz
[2013] [ a] INFO : [handleMessage] Handling messages ...
[2013] [ b] INFO : [handleMessage] The message received is: [OS     OS-EVNTSVR0-H                 20130404125956465000RFST  M430   F               ]
[2013] [ c] INFO : [handleMessage] Complete handling message.
[2013] [ a] INFO : [handleMessage] Handling messages ...
[2013] [ b] INFO : [handleMessage] The message received is: [OS     OS-EVNTSVR0-H                 20130404135956465000RFST  M430   F               ]
[2013] [ c] INFO : [handleMessage] Complete handling message.

$ zcat test.log.gz | perl -ne 'if (/The message received is:/) { push @a, ($_ =~ /\b(\d{20})[A-Z]{4}\b/) } }{ print join "\n", sort @a' | sort
20130404125956465000
20130404135956465000
```

This works If your timestamps are separate words and of the form `20 digits + 4 upperspace characters` (you might need to tweak the regex). Does this do what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. This works.. But some occasions separate word is not the same as 20 digits + 4 uppercase.. 20 digits may vary. only first 16 characters should taken as time stamp..